# Phrase for something that is always out or reach/you almost have but never can get

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, metaphors

I believe there is a two-word phrase for something that is always just out of reach for you and which you cannot ever seem to get.  (It is **not** *Tantalus* or anything having to do with Tantalus, please).

It’s like a girl you like and want to date, and it almost happens a bunch of times but never materializes. You’d say, “She’s my **__ __**.”

I keep thinking *dark horse*, but that’s not it. Any help?

Comment: It's not a flattering description, but "white whale" ala Moby Dick might work.

Comment: I know what you're thinking, and it's just on the tip of my tongue... It's much more concise and idiomatic than "just beyond my/his grasp," but means the same thing, right? Or is it more in the vein of "close call"?

Comment: @Jeremy, I’d say describing the girl as your white whale is definitely a sure-fire way to make sure you _never_ get to date her!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I once heard two larger women with beautiful accents talking in a bar. I asked "Are the ladies from England?" and one replies "wails". So I correct myself and ask "Are the whales from England?" Sure enough, I _never_ got to date either one of them!

Answer (score 12):

I can't think of a way to express that without borrowing from literature, so I would probably use 'Holy Grail'.  When referring to something other than a girl, it'd probably be 'White Whale'.

Answer (score 7):

The one-word adjective is *elusive*, meaning "difficult to find, catch, or achieve," as in "she's my *elusive* dream-girl".

Comment: actually, "dream girl" (sans 'elusive') might just be the best answer

Comment: Perhaps not the term the original asker was looking for, but it was exactly what *I* was looking for when Google led me here.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible two-word phrases. But if you kept thinking about *dark horse*, then maybe *wild-goose chase* is what you're looking for.

From the [Free Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wild-goose%20chase),

> **wild–goose chase** *noun*
>   a complicated or lengthy and usually fruitless pursuit or search

Answer (score 1):

This does not quite answer your question (because it is not two words), but the phrase that comes to mind is "so close yet so far away," "so close but so far away," or some other very similar variation of that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of the **brass ring**. The brass ring is originally a reward sought by some carrousel riders, who would try to grab it as they pass by the dispenser. The dispenser also held iron rings, so luck and timing played a big part in the chance of success.

You can find the description in multiple places, including [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brass%20ring).

The brass ring is considered elusive, hard to get, a challenge to obtain, and seekers of the brass ring may often end up with the iron ring instead. As a consolation, the iron ring is as worthless as grabbing nothing, by the way.

*The brass ring* is now a metaphor for a goal that provides ultimate fulfillment in an endeavor and is only achievable by a few.

Answer (score 1):

How about **impossible dream** ?

The song *The Quest* by Mitch Leigh contains the phrase, though I don't know if he coined it. This [azlyrics site](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/elvispresley/theimpossibledream.html) has the words as sung by Elvis Presley.

> To dream the impossible dream
>  To fight the unbeatable foe
>  To
>   bear the unbearable sorrow
>  To run where the brave dare not go
>
> To write the unwritable wrong [sic]
>  To be better far than you are
>  To
>   try when your arms are too weary
>  The reach the unreachable
>   star
>
> This is my quest, to follow that star
>  No matter how hopeless,
>   No matter how far
>  To fight for the right
>   Without question or pause
>   To be willing to march into hell
>   For a heavenly cause
>
> And I know if I'll only be true
>  To this glorious quest
>  That my
>   heart will be peaceful and calm
>  When I'm laid to my rest
>
> And the world would be better for this
>  That one man scorned and
>   covered with scars
>  Still strove with his last ounce of courage
>   To reach the unreachable star

Answer (score 0):

A Math geek would tell you to say

> She is my asymptotic fantasy.

Concerning a future career that you would never attain:

> Becoming another Bill Gates or Steve Jobs will be my asymptotic failure.

Concerning the goals of a corp:

> We are always trying to reach beyond ourselves. We place goals before us that are barely within our reach. Our goal of becoming the largest corporation in the world is our asymptotic goal.

Also:

> Perfection is an asymptotic goal.

From dictionary:

> [as·ymp·tote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/asymptotic)
>   n.
>   A line whose distance to a given curve tends to zero. An asymptote may or may not intersect its associated curve.
>   [*Ultimately from Greek asumpttos, not intersecting : a-, not; see a-1 + sumpttos, intersecting (from sumpiptein, sumpt-, to converge : sun-, syn- + piptein, to fall; see pet- in Indo-European roots).*]
>   asymp·totic (-ttk), asymp·toti·cal adj.
>   asymp·toti·cal·ly adv.

Ref:[Article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote).

Answer (score 0):

You can say,

> She's my mission impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Unicorn!** Unicorn is the answer. Mythological creature said to be beautiful and majestic, strongly linked to desire.

Answer (score -1):

As a single word, "she's my unobtainable muse"

Comment: Could you please include the definition of "muse" in your post? It does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @SoylentGreen, google "unobtainable muse" and you will see this is a common usage. (Cf. http://robinfrederick.com/poets-and-muses/, http://forums.thefashionspot.com/f81/here-muse-54023.html, http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=E098B-UycUUC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=unobtainable+muse&source=bl&ots=4wYHIIp7nU&sig=07w5RrwlIaPDjFyGPriJKWTPPgo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ptzFUqK3OYn_lAXAqYDADQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=unobtainable%20muse&f=false, http://www.scotsman.com/news/here-is-the-muse-1-682682)

Comment: Here are two quotations from the OED: "▸a1393   Gower Confessio Amantis (Fairf.) viii. 3140 (MED),   My muse..seith it schal be for my beste..That y nomore of love make.
c1450  (▸c1393)    Chaucer Scogan 38   Ne thynke I never of slep to wake my muse, That rusteth in my shethe stille in pees." They imply a sense of unattainability vis-a-vis. def. 2 the allusive usage in application to a person.

Comment: Good points. In that case, I respectfully suggest that you modify your answer to "unobtainable muse" as you have written in your comment, as that two word phrase carries with it much more meaning than the standalone word "muse", and thus answers the question much better.  Is there a reason you chose "muse" and not "unobtainable muse" in your answer?

Comment: @SoylentGreen, changed. Reason, I originally just put muse: I thought muse was more obvious than it is.